# Uneven count data - which road to take? SPSS

Tags: spss, nonparametric

Stats novice- I'm wondering which road to take when it comes to uneven count data. My data consist of quantities for 22 plastic debris types (bottles, caps, lids, bags...) found on a beach. As they are count data, I suppose they can't follow a normal distribution, hence I should look at non-parametric tests. Could I carry on with a Kruskal Wallis test and suitable post-hoc or should I run a Poisson regression on the data? My aim is to observe any differences in quantities for the 22 types i.e. see which type differ from another. Thank you.

[image: Here is what the data looks like]

Comment: I'm curious what you are really counting. Maybe explanation of a few lines in your table will help. I see an entry with 12 caps next to entries with 1 cap. Is each row a different 'event'? Is each of the 12 caps (maybe all in one place from a couple of six-packs of something) as important as each of the single caps? Are you counting 'littering incidents' or individual pieces of debris? // On another issue: do you really have as part of your null hypothesis that the number of caps is equal to the number of spoons? Are you interested in whether some kinds of litter are more common than others?

Comment: @BruceET thanks for your input. Each row is a different input yes, from different places on a 1km stretch of a beach. Each concentration is important yes, and I don't want to exclude too much data. Therefore I'm counting individual pieces of debris by type, so for example 17 caps have been found in total, compared to 14 bags and so on. I'm trying to figure out whether some kinds of litter are more common indeed.

Comment: I anticipated that response, just wanted to make sure. So my Answer should be helpful. Question now is whether you have enough litter counts to detect important differences in prevalence. What is your total count? // Past bed time here, will look back in the AM.

Comment: @BruceET; no worries, and many thanks for your detailed answer. I have 3210 debris found in total, for 19 types of debris. Some debris are reported in far more quantities than other (for example bottles have been found 12 times, for a total of 400 bottles, whereas bags have been found 6 times, total n= 54). So if I understand correctly, I should start with a chi squared test of equally likely outcomes?

Comment: Sounds like you're on track. Wishing you success with this.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in knowing whether pieces of each of the 22
kinds of plastic litter are equally likely to be found,
then that would be like rolling a 22-sided die and asking if the 22 faces are equally likely.

In that example,
suppose the first 11 faces are half as likely as the last 11 faces, so that counts will often be substantially
unequal. Here is a simulation of that experiment in R.
With 200 rolls of the die, we have a good chance
of detecting the bias towards higher numbers with a chi-squared test
of equally likely outcomes.

```
set.seed(2020)
pr = c(rep(1,11),rep(2,11)) 
roll = sample(1:22, 200, rep=T, prob=pr)
x = tabulate(roll);  x   # 22 counts
[1]  6  8  5  4  9  6  7  8  5  2  4 14 10  4 10 13 17 16 14 12 12 14
chisq.test(x)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  x
X-squared = 44.42, df = 21, p-value = 0.002062
```

In the output above notice that in vector `x` the counts
tend to be greater toward the end than toward the beginning. The numbers in `pr` don't add to 1 as probabilities should, but the `sample` procedure with
scale them to sum to $1.$ Also, the `given probabilities` are
assumed to be all equal $(1/22$ for each face of the die).
Finally, the P-value 0.002 < 0.05 indicates some faces among the 200 rolls are significantly more likely than others.

The small bit of 'data' you have shown for an illustration
would not be enough to find significant differences
in frequencies of the four types of litter.

```
x = c(8,9,12,14)
chisq.test(x)

   Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  x
X-squared = 2.1163, df = 3, p-value = 0.5486
```

If you had the same proportions, but with 5 times as many
counts in each category (i.e, 40, 45, 60, 70), then the
chi-squared test would have found the counts significantly different, and you could do further tests to see which
categories are significantly different from which other ones.

> Please understand that multiplying in this way is illegal, so the only value in the output below is to give a vague idea how large counts might have to be for you to have a chance of finding interesting differences.

```
chisq.test(5*x)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  5 * x
X-squared = 10.581, df = 3, p-value = 0.01422
```

*Addendum per Comments:*

Consider that you found 20 Forks, ten pairs of Spoons, and five instances with 4 bags. That's 20 of each, which a chi-squared test would count as equal prevalences. But a K-W test would find
a highly significant difference:

```
x1 = rep(1, 20)
x2 = rep(2, 10)
x3 = rep(4, 5)
sum(x1); sum(x2); sum(x3)
[1] 20
[1] 20
[1] 20
list(x1,x2,x3)
[[1]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

[[2]]
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

[[3]]
 [1] 4 4 4 4 4

kruskal.test(list(x1,x2,x3))

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  list(x1, x2, x3)
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 34, df = 2, 
  p-value = 4.14e-08
```

Comment: looking at the chi-square test in more detail, I see it is best used for categorical data and to compare one group from another. Therefore I'm puzzled, as my data contains quantities for each plastic type found on a beach. If I want to know differences between types, could I not run a Kruskal Wallis test with a post hoc?

Comment: Chi-sq categories are Fork, Spoon, Bag, etc. // If you're counting 1 & 17 caps as two data points, I wonder about basis for K-W test. Do counts 1,2,3,1 mean something different to you than getting 1 seven times? Before you said "I'm counting individual pieces of debris by type, so for example 17 caps have been found in total, compared to 14 bags and so on." (And even if your counts are somehow suitable for K-W, looks as if you'd have massive ties at '1's and maybe at '2's.)

Comment: I understand. I'll try that possibility as well. My aim is to see the how the amount of debris found for one type differ from another. What I could do is sum up all the quantities found for each group and run either a KW or chi-square.

Comment: Point is that chi-sq and K-W are take data in different formats and rejection of $H_0$ means fundamentally different things in the two cases. You should focus on data and test that are really what you want, and do the _one_ appropriate test. Statistical tests ought not be treated as if items at a cafeteria.